# Barrow's Method For Slope of Tangent Line

Tags: calculus, tangent-line, slope

I want to find the slop of the tangent line to the curve $2x^{3}y+4.5y-xy^{2}=8
$ at point (0,16/5) using Barrow's method. Here's what I've done.

- Substitute x with x+e and y with y+a
  $2(x^{3}+3ex^{2}+3e^{2}+e^{3})(y+a)+4.5(y+a)-(x+e)(y^{2}+2ay+y^{2})=8$
  $2(x^{3}y+x^{2}a+3ex^{2}y+3ex^{2}a+3e^{2}y+3e^{2}a+e^{3}y+e^{3}a)+4.5y+4.5a-y^{2}x-2ayx-y^{2}x-ey^{2}-2aye-ey^{2}=8$
- I now remove terms with powers of e or a or products of the two 
  $2(x^{3}y+x^{2}a+3ex^{2}y+3ex^{2}a)+4.5y+4.5a-y^{2}x-2ayx-y^{2}x-ey^{2}-2aye-ey^{2}=8$
- Remember $2x^{3}y+4.5y-xy^{2}=8$ so I can replace those terms with 8 which sets the equation equal to 0 when subtracted
  $2x^{2}a+6ex^{2}y+6ex^{2}a+4.5a-y^{2}x-2ayx-ey^{2}-2aye-ey^{2}=8$

I'm confused as to where I go from here

Comment: Subtract the original equation, substitute the coordinates of the point for $x$ and $y$, set $e=1$ and solve for $a$.

Comment: $(0,16/5)$ is not on the curve, $(0,16/9)$ is though.

Comment: The tangent cone method: Map the tangent point to the origin $(X,Y)\to(x,y-\frac{16}{9}),$ so the inverse is $(x,y)\to(X,Y+\frac{16}{9}):$ $$2X^3(Y+\frac{16}{9})+\frac92(Y+\frac{16}{9})-X(Y+\frac{16}{9})^2-8=0$$
expand and take the linear terms $\frac{729Y-512X}{162}=0.$ Scaling and mapping back we get the tangent line $729(y-\frac{16}{9})-512x=0,$ or 
$y=\frac{512}{729}x+\frac{16}{9}.$

Answer (score 0):

Barrow sets $f(x+e,y+a)=f(x,y)$ and discards terms that are quadratic or higher in $e$ and $a$. This equation is equivalent to $f(x+e,y+a)-f(x,y)=0$, so subtract the original function from what you’ve ended up with. In the resulting expression, $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates of the point at which you’re computing the tangent, while $e$ and $a$ are “infinitesimal” displacements from it. Once you plug in the values of $x$ and $y$ for the point, you should end up with an equation of a line in $e$ and $a$. I hope that you know how to extract the slope from that yourself.